# Convert Polynominal to Binominal - Thousands of columns

Tags: r

I've a dataset with 100 columns (which name is Col_1,Col_2...Col_100) that have results like: "A","B","C"... I don't know ao many diferent characters have in all dataset. I'm trying to convert each value to a column to have a matrix like:

```
A   B   C   D
0   1   0   1
1   1   0   1
```

I'm trying with this:

```
library(reshape2)
train <- read.csv("train.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")
train

recast(train, id ~ value, id.var = 1, fun.aggregate = function(x) (length(x) > 0) + 0L)
```

But I'm getting the following errors:

```
Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
  n must be a positive integer
In addition: Warning messages:
1: attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped 
2: In split_indices(.group, .n) :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

What I can do to return the table that I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for. The first step collects the possible values. The second step makes each variable aware of the potential values. This allows `table` to produce 0 counts when a particular value is missing so that `rbind` will construct the proper output.

```
# collect all possible values
allLevels <- levels(unlist(sapply(df, unique)))
# provide all levels to each variable in the data.frame
dfNew <- data.frame(lapply(df, function(i) factor(i, levels=allLevels)))

# produce the count for each variable
do.call(rbind, lapply(dfNew, table))
  a b c d e g i j
x 3 2 8 2 0 0 0 0
y 0 0 2 4 4 1 3 1
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(x=sample(letters[1:4], 15, replace=TRUE),
                 y=sample(letters[3:10], 15, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: @Imo thanks for your response. I'm getting all the values as N/A, is normal?

Comment: With the example I provided, or your original dataset? If with your original data set, then your should, at a minimum, provide the first 10 lines of `str(df)` where df is the name of your data.frame.

Comment: How can I do that? Sorry I'm very new at R

Comment: Type `str(df)` into your R console (replace df with the name of your data.frame).  Then copy the first 10 lines of the result into your above question.